# RNN layer returns input_length as unknown in keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am now using RNN layer for encoding input documents like below. But I am not sure why RNN layer cannot detect input sequence length? So I think last `p`'s shape should be `(?, doc_maxlen, rnn_h_size)` instead of `(?, ?, rnn_h_size)`. Where's wrong point?

```
rnn_h_size = 10
embd_size = 100
doc_maxlen= 10418
doc = Input((doc_maxlen,), name='Doc_Input')
embd_layer = Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embd_size)
embd_doc = embd_layer(doc) # (?, doc_maxlen, embd_size)
p =GRU(rnn_h_size, return_sequences=True)(embd_doc) # (?, ?, 10), why not (?, doc_maxlen, rnn_h_size)?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `model.summary()` you will see the dimensions you want to see.

Even though, variable lengths are supported in keras and having `None` in the summary for the length dimension won't change how your model works in any way (if you don't intend to use layers that change this dimension).

Example:

```
from keras.models import Model
model = Model(doc,p)
model.summary()
```